# Egg Box of a semigroup in GAP

Tags: semigroups, gap

How can I draw the egg box of D class of a semigroup with GAP. I used function `DrawDClasses(S,"DClasses")`, but it does not work and it asks me to install `gsviwer` but I already  have `gsviwer` on my system.

Comment: which operating system do you have?

Comment: The same question has been asked in the GAP Forum: http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2016/005365.html and an answer from an expert has been provided. Could you please continue discussion there by email?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps worth to answer here, since GAP Forum will not permit attachment. For me, the process described in the [manual](https://gap-packages.github.io/Semigroups/doc/chap4.html#X78476D2B82CE400D) and [GAP Forum](http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2016/005365.html) works perfectly: I have [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) installed, and after

```
LoadPackage("semigroups");
S:=FullTransformationSemigroup(3);
Splash(DotDClasses(S));
```

I see the following picture (opened in my tool to view PDFs):

[image]

The explanation why it does not work for you and how to make it working depends on your operating system, the software you have, and the way you've installed it - such discussion is out of scope for this site, and I would not be surprised if this question will be closed in the future. I suggest to [contact GAP Support](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/People/supportgroup.html) telling  details of your operating system and providing exact input and output in your case, and I hope that we will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your time, my operation system is windows 8.1, and the version of my gap is 4.8.4. This function dose not work for me and the function FileString("name-of-a-file.dot", DotDClasses(S)); create a .dot file but dot -Tpdf name-of-a-file > name-of-a-file.pdf  dose not work. I could convert  the .dot file by some other programs but my problem is I need a  egg box with interior data  like the one in here http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/sgpviz/doc/chap3.html